# Extraer texto que contenga un string especifico

Tags: linux, string, awk, sed, gnu

Tengo un archivo que es asi:

```
#2021/05/12
id:dato
nombre:dato
producto:dato2
servicio:dato

#2021/05/12
id:dato
nombre:dato
producto:dato3
servicio:dato
```

Necesito sacar todo el texto que empieza simpre con # y termina con una linea en blanco que contenga el valor "producto:dato2" y mandarlo a otro archivo.

Estoy en Linux he intentado usar

```
sed -n '/#/,/<blank>/p'> prueba.txt
```

para delimitar la extraccion del texto pero no se como solo sacar los que sean "producto:dato2".

Answer (score 3):

Con GNU Awk puedes hace que cada registro sea un párrafo imponiendo que el separador de registros sea el salto de línea. Entonces es solo cuestión de buscar aquellos párrafos que tienen este texto:

```
$ gawk 'BEGIN{RS=""} /producto:dato2/' fichero
#2021/05/12
id:dato
nombre:dato
producto:dato2
servicio:dato
```

Comment: Perfecto!. Es exactamente lo que buscaba. Muchisimas gracias!!!

Comment: Qué bien :) Considera aceptar la respuesta si te resolvió la duda, tal y como se explica en [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)